# Chaining keyframes in react-spring

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

I'm trying to make a jiggle-type animation for a cta button that runs after a specified delay to draw the viewers attention onto it.
But it doesn't quite work as expected because if you see the spring object

```js
useSpring({
    loop: true,
    delay: 1000,
    config: { tension: 200, friction: 5 },
    from: { scaleX: 1, scaleY: 1, y: 0 },
    to: [
      { scaleX: 1.1, scaleY: 0.9, y: 3 },
      { scaleX: 1, scaleY: 1, y: 0 }
    ]
  });
```

I have two keyframes in the `to` property for that I want it to shrink a bit before jumping back to its original size.
But the issue is that it adds that `delay` between the two keyframes as you can see in my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-pike-xkc93?file=/src/App.js) example. I instead want the keyframes to run instantly without a delay while keeping the delay for each complete jiggle.
The docs of this library ain't really helpful to me tbh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels like a delay but actually, it is just the first animation keyframe finishing up before the next one starts.

Try adding duration to your config `config: { tension: 200, friction: 5, duration: 200 },` or
Try adding clamp to your config `config: { tension: 200, friction: 5, clamp: true },`

React-Spring uses physics animations and I got tripped up on this too when I was starting. The interpolations are happening on a small scale so that you don't notice that they are still running.

```
import { animated, useSpring, config } from "react-spring";
import styled from "styled-components";

export default function App() {
  const jiggleSpring = useSpring({
    loop: true,
    delay: 2000,
    config: config.stiff,
    from: { scaleX: 1, scaleY: 1, y: 0 },
    to: [
      { scaleX: 1.1, scaleY: 0.9, y: 3 },
      // I don't want the delay between these keyframes
      { scaleX: 1, scaleY: 1, y: 0 }
    ]
  });
```

I would also try importing configs individually and trying the different ones out.

Comment: adding `clamp` does the job. But could you please explain what difference does `clamp` make here? The docs say- *"when true, stops the spring once it overshoots its boundaries"*. But I don't quite get it

Comment: yeah! animations in react-spring are literally on a spring. Just like any other spring, they oscillate back and forth until friction brings them to a stop. Adding a clamp in real life keeps the spring from oscillating like this. 

Here is a picture of a car suspension with a clamp on it: https://www.focusfanatics.com/attachments/p2140039-jpg.14353/

The vernacular in react-spring is modeled off of real life, if you just look up the words outside of the animation world it can make more sense :)